# What is the definition of this person's voice ? 引きつった呻きを上げた

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

Can someone help me understand the meaning of **引きつった呻きを上げた** ?
(From my understanding
引きつった + Face = A frowned face /uncomfortable

But i don't know about 引きつった + a voice  = ?? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is an irregular use of 引きつる, but 引きつった声 is a common expression.

First, the following from [a dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D%E6%94%A3%E3%82%8B/) (emphasis added)

> ひき‐つ・る【引き×攣る】 ［動ラ五（四）］
>
> １ 痙攣 (けいれん) する。「足が―・る」
>
> ２ かたくこわばる。「緊張で顔が―・っている」**「怒りに声が―・る」**
>
> ３ やけどなどで皮膚がつっぱる。

Practically 引きつった声で話す means (to me) that someone is in anger but trying to sound normal yet not completely successfully, that is, the tone indicates the the speaker's anger.

Now it is hard to imagine 引きつった呻き声 (even with more context). Most probably 引きつった here means *suppressed*, just like the 引きつった声 is a voice where anger is suppressed (not completely).

Comment: so "muffled voice" ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. The guy(?) is moaning trying not to scream.